# java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xml-parsing, android-sqlite

While compiling, I am getting a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` error.

I googled a lot, but I still can't find a solution.
Kindly help me with my code.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_GET_LOGIN_DETAILS);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
request.addProperty("loginUsr", user);
request.addProperty("loginPasswd", pass);
envelope.dotNet = true; // to handle .net services asmx/aspx
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL_PROTOCOL + mSettings.getMmpServerpath() + URL_SERVICE_NAME);
ht.debug = true;
String soap_action = NAMESPACE + METHOD_GET_LOGIN_DETAILS;
ht.call(soap_action, envelope);
SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
File mImpOutputFile = Supporter.getImpOutputFilePathByCompany("MobManufacturingProcess", "00",
    "FiGoodsDetails" + ".xml");
if (!mImpOutputFile.exists()) {
    Supporter.createFile(mImpOutputFile);
} else {
    mImpOutputFile.delete(); // to refresh the file
    Supporter.createFile(mImpOutputFile);
}

BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mImpOutputFile, true));

buf.append("<" + "Details" + ">");

buf.append(resultString.toString());

buf.append("</" + "Details" + ">");
result = "success";

buf.close();

} catch (

SocketTimeoutException e)

{
    result = "time out error";
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (

IOException e)

{
    result = "input error";
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (

XmlPullParserException e)

{
    result = "error";
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (

Exception e)

{
    Log.e("tag", "error", e);
    result = "error";
}
new DataLoadToDBOperation().execute();
return result;

}

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /* String[] result=totVal.get(totVal.size()); */
    // super.onPostExecute(totVal);

    if (result.equals("success")) {
        new DataLoadToDBOperation().execute();

    } else {
        mToastMsg.showToast(LogInActivity.this, "Invalid Username or Password");
    }

    dialog.cancel();
}

}

private class DataLoadToDBOperation extends AsyncTask < String, String, String > {
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public DataLoadToDBOperation() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(LogInActivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

        String errMsg = "";

        try {

            String result = "";

            DataLoader fileLoader = new DataLoader(LogInActivity.this, mDBHelper, user);

            List < String > importFileList = mSupporter.loadImportFileList();

            int totImpFile = importFileList.size();

            File salPer_folder_path = Supporter.getImportFolderPath(user);

            List < String > compList = mSupporter.getFolderNames(salPer_folder_path);

            int compSize = compList.size();

            if (compSize != 0) {

                startDBTransaction("db data loading"); // to start db
                // transaction

                for (int c = 0; c < compList.size(); c++) {

                    String serCompName = compList.get(c);

                    for (int i = 0; i < totImpFile; i++) {

                        String fileName = importFileList.get(i);

                        if ((c > 0) && (fileName.equals("FigoodsDetail"))) { // to
                            // load
                            // FigoodsDetail
                            // data
                            // once
                            continue; // to continue for other files
                        }

                        mImpOutputFile = Supporter.getImpOutputFilePathByCompany(spCode, serCompName,
                        fileName + ".xml");

                        if (mImpOutputFile.exists()) {
                            InputStream inputStream;

                            inputStream = new FileInputStream(mImpOutputFile);
                            String[] resultArray = fileLoader.parseDocument(inputStream);

                            result = resultArray[0];
                            errMsg = resultArray[1];

                            if (!result.equals("success")) {
                                mDBHelper.mEndTransaction();
                                break;
                            }

                        } else {
                            result = "File not available";
                            mDBHelper.mEndTransaction();
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    if (!result.equals("success")) { // to break from
                        // executing other
                        // companies
                        break;
                    }

                }
                endDBTransaction(); // to end db transaction

            } else {
                result = "File not available";
            }

            return result;
        } catch (Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
            String errorCode = "Err-CLS-2";
            LogFileCreator.appendLog(errorCode + " : " + exe.getMessage() + "\n" + errMsg);
            String result = "error";
            return result;
        }
    }

    /*
     * @Override protected void onPostExecute(final String result) { if (dialog
     * != null) { if (dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); } }
     * 
     * if (result.equals("success")) {
     * 
     * mCmpnyNameList = loadListOfCompany();
     * 
     * mAdptSpnCompany = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LogInActivity.this,
     * android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mCmpnyNameList);
     * 
     * mSpnCompany.setAdapter(mAdptSpnCompany);
     * 
     * // to delete file after loaded to db mSupporter.deleteFileFolder(user);
     * 
     * mSupporter.navigateTo(MainMenu.class);
     * 
     * } else if (result.equals("nosd")) {
     * mToastMsg.showToast(LogInActivity.this, "Sd card required"); } else if
     * (result.equals("parsing error")) { mToastMsg
     * .showToast(LogInActivity.this, "Error during parsing the data"); } else
     * if (result.equals("File not available")) {
     * mToastMsg.showToast(LogInActivity.this, "File not available"); } else {
     * mToastMsg.showToast(LogInActivity.this, "Errorrrrrrrrr"); }
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait until the data is loaded");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values) {}
}
```

Comment: Show full error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new DataLoadToDBOperation().execute();
```

is the problem. `AsyncTask` uses an internal handler to call some of its callbacks on the ui thread, and this handler has to be instantiate on the ui thread. Get rid of that call from `doInBackground`